# What filesystem does MSR use?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 installation on a gpt disk. I know what MSR (MicroSoftReserved) partition is and what is it used for, but just for some tinkering around, I would like to know the filesystem.

Comment: MSR is created during install, but it is not formatted. So it does not contain any filesystem, and all its bytes are random.

Comment: All bytes are zero actually, not random. Just checked.

Answer (score 1):

**None.** Quoting [Wikipedia on MSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition):

> A Microsoft Reserved Partition (MSR) is a partition of a data storage device, which is created simply to reserve a portion of disk space for possible subsequent use by a Windows operating system installed on a separate partition. **No meaningful data is stored within the MSR**; though from the MSR, chunks may be taken for the creation of new partitions, which themselves may contain data structures.

It's just a placeholder.